# Difference between passing by reference with Objects and primitives

Tags: c++

Let's say we have 2 numbers and we want to swap them with a method using call by reference.  It would look something like this:

```
int main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    swap(a, b);
}

void swap(int &a, int &b) {
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

It would swap the values of a and b, even in the main-method because it changed it using the reference.

Now, lets take some sample class "Cat"

```
class Cat{
public:
    char _name[20];

    Cat(char name[]);
    ~Cat();

    static void meowName(Cat &cat);
};
```

So I thought, as we pass a Reference (Address) I could do this:

```
void Cat::meowName(Cat &cat){
    Cat *pCat = cat; // as variable Cat should be an address already
    printf("My name is: %s\n", pCat->name);
}
```

Of course, I need to do `*pCat = &cat` but why exactly? 
Aren't we actually passing the address of the variable but simply the object itself instead of a copy of the variable?

P.s. dont mind the meowName method, I wanted to understand difference between calling methods by instance and per reference. :)

thanks

Comment: Why did you tag this with C?  C does not do pass-by-reference.

Comment: A reference variable is an alias, that is, another name for an already existing variable. A pointer contains the address of another variable. PS. References are a c++ datatype.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am still kinda mixing up terms :), pass-by-reference is what c++ does here with parameter type being &a, right? Because C is call-by-reference but does not have this "pass-by-reference"?

Comment: A reference is not an address.   `cat` is a reference to a object passed by the caller.   `&cat` obtains the address of that object.

Comment: @ZesaRex C is *strictly* pass-by-value.  If you modify the contents of a passed variable in a C function, the original variable in the calling function remains unchanged.  **Always**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle okay but you can pass the address of a variable to a method and change the variable using the address, thus changing the variable in the caller aswell, right? Means, C is still pass-by-value because parameters are still always a copy instead of the actual reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually passing by reference is different from passing by pointer, the reference is a second name of a variable

```
int a = 2;
int & b = a;
```

in this case b is not a pointer, it is a second name of variable a, that is same variable with single memory address that can be accessed by two names, so you cannot do this

```
int * c = b; //this is wrong
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
 Cat &cat = value;
```

cat doesn't hold the address, it is a reference to the value. hence you have to use the address of operator (&) to assign it to a pointer.

```
 Cat *ptr = &cat;
```